# Display Latitude and Longitude with cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation on phonegap

Tags: cordova, plugins, geolocation, phonegap

I'am new to phonegap and it's plugins.
I'am using cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation plugin,my problem is that I can't get to display as an alert the latitude or longitude . I can't figure it out which variable is storing this data . I would apreciate if anyone could help me out and explain me what variable has the latitude or longitude so I can alert in a dialog box.
here is the code I'am using.

```
    <div>GPS</div>
    <button onclick="gps()" id="st">gps</button><br>
    <button onclick="pos()" id="st3">my position</button><br>
    <button onclick="gps_end()" id="st2">gps end</button><br>
    <button onclick="stats()" id="st5">status</button><br>`

<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">`
    function onDeviceReady() {
    BackgroundGeolocation.configure({
    locationProvider: BackgroundGeolocation.ACTIVITY_PROVIDER,
    desiredAccuracy: BackgroundGeolocation.HIGH_ACCURACY,
    stationaryRadius: 50,
    distanceFilter: 50,
    notificationTitle: 'Background tracking',
    notificationText: 'enabled',
    debug: true,
    interval: 10000,
    fastestInterval: 5000,
    activitiesInterval: 10000,
    url: 'xxxxx',
    httpHeaders: {
      'X-FOO': 'bar'
    },
    // customize post properties
    postTemplate: {
      lat: '@latitude',
      lon: '@longitude',
      foo: 'bar' // you can also add your own properties
    }
    });

    BackgroundGeolocation.on('location', function(location) {
    // handle your locations here
    // to perform long running operation on iOS
    // you need to create background task
    BackgroundGeolocation.startTask(function(taskKey) {
      // execute long running task
      // eg. ajax post location
      // IMPORTANT: task has to be ended by endTask
      BackgroundGeolocation.endTask(taskKey);
    });
    });

    BackgroundGeolocation.on('stationary', function(stationaryLocation) {
    // handle stationary locations here
    });

    BackgroundGeolocation.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log('[ERROR] BackgroundGeolocation error:', error.code, 
    error.message);
     });

    BackgroundGeolocation.on('start', function() {
    console.log('[INFO] BackgroundGeolocation service has been started');
    });

    BackgroundGeolocation.on('stop', function() {
    console.log('[INFO] BackgroundGeolocation service has been stopped');
    });

    BackgroundGeolocation.on('authorization', function(status) {
    console.log('[INFO] BackgroundGeolocation authorization status: ' + status);
    if (status !== BackgroundGeolocation.AUTHORIZED) {

      setTimeout(function() {
        var showSettings = confirm('App requires location tracking permission. 
        Would you like to open app settings?');
        if (showSetting) {
          return BackgroundGeolocation.showAppSettings();
        }
        }, 1000);
        }
        });

       BackgroundGeolocation.on('background', function() {
    console.log('[INFO] App is in background');
    // you can also reconfigure service (changes will be applied immediately)
    BackgroundGeolocation.configure({ debug: true });
    });

    BackgroundGeolocation.on('foreground', function() {
    console.log('[INFO] App is in foreground');
    BackgroundGeolocation.configure({ debug: false });
      });

    BackgroundGeolocation.checkStatus(function(status) {
    console.log('[INFO] BackgroundGeolocation service is running', 
    status.isRunning);
    console.log('[INFO] BackgroundGeolocation services enabled', 
    status.locationServicesEnabled);
    console.log('[INFO] BackgroundGeolocation auth status: ' + 
        status.authorization);
      alert("entre a la funcion checkstatus")

    // you don't need to check status before start (this is just the example)
    if (!status.isRunning) {
      BackgroundGeolocation.start(); //triggers start on start event
    }
     });

    }

      document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

      function gps(){
      alert("Starts GPS")
            BackgroundGeolocation.start();
            BackgroundGeolocation.checkStatus();
       alert ("GPS ON")
                    }




    function gps_end(){
     BackgroundGeolocation.checkStatus();
        alert("Ending gps")
     BackgroundGeolocation.stop();
    alert("No Gps")
                    }


     function pos() {
      alert("start pos function")
        BackgroundGeolocation.getCurrentLocation(
            function (locations) {
                alert(locations.latitude);
                                 }); 
                }

       function stats() {
              BackgroundGeolocation.checkStatus();
              var watchID = BackgroundGeolocation.getCurrentLocation(onSuccess, 
    onError, options);
                function onSuccess(position) {
                                                BackgroundGeolocation.start();
                                                lat=position.coords.latitude;
                                                long=position.coords.longitude;
                                                alert(long)         
                                             }
                    }

    function onError(position){

    show_alert('GPS','Unable to load GPS data.'+position.message,'OK'); 
                                }   


     </script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The configuration has been updated for quicker location lock.

Change to this, to see what's going on:

```
BackgroundGeolocation.on('location', function(location) {
    alert("Current location: " + JSON.stringify(location));
});
```

This is of course provided you get any location at all. You should get at least one. Then you might have to move enough distance before you get a new one.

Did you add `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation"/>` to config.xml or installed the plugin from the command line?

If you don't get any questions about permissions after making a clean install of the app, that's probably the reason for not getting any locations.

Also, see if you get any JavaScript errors.

You can report an issue at GitHub if you haven't already.

This is the configuration I use at the moment:

```
    var options = {
        locationProvider: BackgroundGeolocation.ACTIVITY_PROVIDER,
        desiredAccuracy: BackgroundGeolocation.MEDIUM_ACCURACY),
        stationaryRadius: 25,
        distanceFilter: 20,
        notificationTitle: 'Tracking position in the background',
        notificationText: 'enabled',
        debug: false,
        interval: 10000,
        fastestInterval: 5000,
        activitiesInterval: 5000,
        stopOnTerminate: false,
        startOnBoot: false,
        startForeground: true,
        pauseLocationUpdates: false,
        stopOnStillActivity: true,
        saveBatteryOnBackground: false
```

And this in config.xml:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation">
    <variable name="GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="11+" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION" value="23+" />
    <variable name="ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="The app needs background location tracking" />
    <variable name="MOTION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Accelerometer use increases battery efficiency by intelligently toggling location tracking" />
</plugin>
```

and this is what I extract in the location event:

```
    var timestamp = position.time;
    var latitude = position.latitude;
    var longitude = position.longitude;
    var accuracy = position.accuracy;
    var altitude = position.altitude;
    var speed = position.speed;
    var heading = position.bearing;
```

Comment: Thanks por your answer. I will try it right  now and tell you about it.